# how to get value from shared object vb net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

vb :

```
Protected Shared Customer As String
```

aspx :

```
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" Style="display: none">
    <div style="height: 60px">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
               <a></a>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
</asp:Panel>
```

I want to get value of Customer , I've tried like this :

```
<a><%=Customer%></a>
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: A `Shared` Customer in a web-application, means that *all* users of that site will see the same customer - is that what you want? You may want to investigate `Session`

Comment: I think you must use it with it's class name (ClassName.Customer) or use Application variables for sharing your object.